# Link to rep gain in Super User links to SO when accessed from SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, notifications

See [comment below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425915/link-to-rep-gain-in-superuser-links-to-so-when-accessed-from-so?noredirect=1#comment968519_425915): Already [reported on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391952/positive-reputation-notification-for-edit-approvals-uses-relative-url-which-cau).

---

I made [an edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1208939) to [a Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1167988/change-screen-resolution-shortcut-with-correct-aspect-ratio-letterboxing). I don't have enough rep to auto-edit, so it went through the approval process and, later, was approved. (I don't have any idea if that's important.)

I saw the notification of acceptance and +2 while in SO. I opened the "Achievements" dropdown, clicked link, and went to [an unrelated question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167988/using-sqlsrv-connect-on-platforms-other-than-windows). The question title in the link is correct, but we all know that's just cosmetic. The question *number* is right (1167988). The domain (*stackoverflow* instead of *superuser*) is not.

[image: shows achievements drop-down open, link "moused over", and link to wrong URL is shown in the "status bar" of the browser]

Comment: Cross-site issue (MSE): [Positive reputation notification for edit approvals uses relative URL, which causes the link to go to the wrong place](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391952/248731)

Comment: @jonrsharpe cool, thanks. Might keep here in case any body looks for it on SO.

Answer (score 6):

This should now be fixed. See [kristinalustig's answer here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/392827/335251):

> Thanks for reporting! I fixed this issue - it was due to a refactoring error in a switch statement determining how we were creating the URL for the Achievements tab. Those dang fall-throughs... Anyway, it's no longer a relative URL so this should work just fine - please let me know if you're still seeing any issues.

Comment: I can confirm this issue is now fixed.